# How to remove link from only one element?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have two div in one `<a>`. I want link to only work on first `<div>`.

This is the code:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 15em;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

#div1info {
  width: 30em;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 16em;
  transition: 1s;
}

#div1:hover+#div1info {
  width: 30em;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: rgb(10, 9, 9);
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 100%;
  margin-left: 16em;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div1info"></div>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

I try change this:

```
<a href="#">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div1info"></div>
</a>
```

To this

```
<a href="#">
        <div id="div1"></div>
</a>
```

But then CSS didn't work.

How I can make the link work on only the first `<div>`? With any language, CSS, jQuery, JS...

If there is no way to do this without changing the HTML structure, change it slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS "didn't work" because when you change the markup structure then you also need to change any style selectors which *depend* on that markup structure.  In this case specifically this one:

```
#div1:hover + #div1info
```

The `#div1info` is no longer a *sibling* of `#div1`.  But is *is* a sibling of the surrounding `a`:

```
a:hover + #div1info
```

For example:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 15em;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

#div1info {
  width: 30em;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 16em;
  transition: 1s;
}

a:hover + #div1info {
  width: 30em;
  height: 25em;
  background-color: rgb(10, 9, 9);
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 100%;
  margin-left: 16em;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="div1"></div>
</a>
<div id="div1info"></div>
```